# Python- xor-ing number series , code optimisation

Tags: python, performance, optimization, xor

I have a series which is defined by 2 inputs, length and start number 
e.g : length = 4 , start number = 17
sample:

> 17 18 19 20
>    21 22 23 /24
>   25 26 /27 28
>    29 /30 31 32

I have to include only n-1 numbers as i go down the rows, i.e

> 17^18^19^20^21^22^23^25^26^29.

I wrote a code to XOR the number series,  But my code hits a time violation on the online compiler. The same code runs well on my local python install.

How can I optimize this further? Is there a way to not XOR every number on the list. I have used only loops that are an absolute must.
Thank you.

```
start   = 17 # these will be input from screen
length  = 4  # between 0 and 2000000000
n = length
tot_num = int()
xor_out = int()
while (n > 0):
    for i in xrange(start,start+n,1):
        xor_out = xor_out ^ i
    start = start + length
    n = n-1
print xor_out
```

Comment: Hint, the `xor` of an even and an odd number is alway odd. So if the last bit of the xor of two consecutive numbers is always 1.

Comment: Going farther: The last bit of xored *even* length is always zero. Or *odd* length is always `1`.

Comment: Is always odd, but how does that help? could you give an example? 1^2^3 would give me 0. is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, the opposite. `1` for even length...

Comment: I'm betting you're supposed to come up with some trick that lets you shortcut to the answer without actually calculating all the intermediary values. Even if you got this down to O(N) complexity, `length` can be up to two billion, which is almost certainly going to be a slog. Maybe you can take advantage of the fact that XORing the same number twice is the same as XORing it zero times? `a ^ b ^ b == a`.

Comment: @Kevin But there are no duplicate entries in the input. they are all unique. And weeding out odd and even entrie will frthur add to the time complexity wont it?